# How to print out elements in a webpage using selenium webdriver (java)

Tags: java, selenium

I am quite new to selenium scripting and in my program wants to print the value present in the elements. I am unable to find the elements. Can someone help?
Website i am using: https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/
Wanting to print the various values in  Mortgage Repayment Summary section.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend checking out some good Selenium tutorials, such as the ones on the [Guru99 site](https://www.guru99.com/first-webdriver-script.html).

Regarding how to locate elements on a page in general, use your browser's developer tools. In Chrome, for example, you can hit F12 or right-click the page and choose "Inspect" to open them. Then there is a small box with an arrow in the top left corner of the developer tools. Click that, then click on the element you're interested in. That will highlight it and show you that element in the DOM. You can explore the DOM to start finding ways to get that element in Selenium, such as any IDs, classes, etc. that are on the elements you want.

From there you'll have to write the selenium to locate it. For your specific page, you might use

```
.findElements(By.className("rw-box"))
```

to get all the rows and then iterate that for the data you care about. Or

```
.findElements(By.className("left-cell"))
```

and

```
.findElements(By.className("right-cell"))
```

to get all of those boxes and iterate through those.

Comment: Got it. i have written that. I am not sure on how to print the values after finding the element by class name. Can you help in that?

Comment: WebElements have a .getText() method that return the text inside that element. So you could print that. BTW, if this ends up working for you please remember to mark my answer as such. Thanks!

Comment: I am using the below code                                                                                             List<WebElement> payment = selenium.findElements(By.className("left-cell"));
  String[] linkTexts = new String[payment.size()];
  int i = 0;
  for (WebElement e : payment) {
   linkTexts[i] = e.getText();
   System.out.println(linkTexts[i]);
   i++;
  }                                                                                                                     But this is printing everything

Comment: You'll need to do a little more work to get the specific value you want from there. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to get from the page, but for example if you want the dollar amounts and dates from each of the left cells, it looks like they're all held in an h3 element. So inside your for loop you could do something like: WebElement value = e.findElement(By.tagName("h3")); System.out.println(value.getText()); If you only want some of those and not others then you'll have to print specific indexes of the list of WebElements.

Comment: List<WebElement> payment = selenium.findElements(By.tagName("h3"));
  String[] linkTexts = new String[payment.size()];
  System.out.println(payment.size());
  int i = 0;
  for (WebElement e : payment) {
   linkTexts[i] = e.getText();
   System.out.println(linkTexts[i]);
  }                                                                                                                    This is giving me all the texts of h3 tag. My question in if i want to store the value of linkTexts[2] and linkTexts[4] into 2 variables, how do i do that?